# Instantiate recordset with ORDER BY Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to create a recordset that is ordered according to a table and the current Orderby property of a certain form. Since the Orderby property will change when the users changes it, I made a function that gets the first field only (It's possible to order it using more than 1 field) in the Orderby property and using it to create an ordered recordset .The field's name given from the getField function is given correctly but I assume that the syntax of `"Set rsAll = ..."` is incorrect which is what I think is causing the code to stop.

**Creating a Recordset in an ordered manner.**

```
Dim rsAll As DAO.Recordset
If Len(Forms("All Patient Sub").OrderBy) > 0 Then
Set rsAll = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [All Patient Info] ORDER BY " & getField(Forms("All Patient Sub").OrderBy)) 'code stops here
Else
Set rsAll = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("All Patient Info")
End If
```

**The function that gets the field name from the Orderby property belonging to the form**

```
Public Function getField(ByVal sorter As String) As String
Debug.Print "Started"
'i = 21 hence [All Patient Info].[ is skipped and starts from the field's name
    For i = 21 To Len(sorter)
        If Mid(sorter, i, 1) = "]" Then
            getField = Mid(sorter, 21, i - 21)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Debug.Print getField
End Function
```

Comment: When you say *"code stops here"*, I assume you mean there is an error.  If so, what does the error message say?  If you meant something other than an error, then what?  I suspect it could be useful to see what this shows you: `Debug.Print "SELECT * FROM [All Patient Info] ORDER BY " & getField(Forms("All Patient Sub").OrderBy))`

Comment: Also what is the output of `Debug.Print getField` ?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous vocabulary, I meant an error has occurred. I tried  `Debug.Print "SELECT * FROM [All Patient Info] ORDER BY " & getField(Forms("All Patient Sub").OrderBy))` and it printed nothing and the output of `Debug.Print getField` can differ from time to time but lets say its DOB.

Comment: **What is the error message?**

Comment: No error message appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really follow your code; however since you just want the first column in the orderBy, how about this:

This function needs to be put in a module:

```
'this returns either " ORDER BY [column name]" or an empty string, if there is no column name to order by
public function OrderByClause(propValue as string) as string
    dim cols as string()

    if propValue = "" then
        OrderByClause = ""
    else
        cols = split(propValue, ",")
        dim junk as string: junk = cols(0)
        if instr(junk, ".") > 0 then
            junk = mid(junk, instr(junk, ".") + 1)
        end if
        OrderByClause = " ORDER BY " & junk
    end if
end function
```

Then in your form:

```
Dim rsAll As DAO.Recordset
Dim src as string
src = OrderByClause(Forms("All Patient Sub").OrderBy & "")
src = "SELECT * FROM [All Patient Info]" & src

Set rsAll = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(src)
```

Since the OrderByClause function always returns a value, you can just call it in your form regardless of what the property is set to; The invocation uses ... & "" to prevent an error if the property is in fact null.